# How to detect variables defined outside the function (or undefined) without running the function in python

Tags: python

I would like a function (let's call it `detect_undefined`) which detects variables used in a function, which are **not** defined inside the function without running it.

Examples:

```py
import numpy as np

def add(a):
    return np.sum(a)

print(detect_undefined(add))
```

Output: `["np"]`

```py
def add(a):
    import numpy as np
    return np.sum(a)

print(detect_undefined(add))
```

Output: `[]`

```py
b = 3


def add(a):
    return a + b

print(detect_undefined(add))
```

Output: `["b"]`

```py
def add(a, b=3):
    return a + b

print(detect_undefined(add))
```

Output: `[]`

It is crucial that the algorithm works without running the function to be examined, i.e. I cannot do something like `try ... except`. ChatGPT suggested to use `inspect` and `ast`, but its suggestion didn't quite work.

Comment: An AST walker is not a bad idea, but are you really asking for [PyRight](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright)?

Comment: What's the context here? What do you need this information for?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent a linter. Several good ones already exist, such as mypy and pylint.

Comment: "trying to reinvent" -> "looking for", because so far I failed to make any of them work for the codes above when it comes to the actual implementation. I'm also sure that it must be an easy and well known task. You guys seem to have an idea. Don't you want to post the actual solution? :)

Comment: A good IDE will also show these as errors, with red squiggles under the variables.

Comment: @Barmar Well, not necessarily errors, just references to global variables. (Which is *usually* a bad idea, but certainly not in the first example, referring to an imported module.)

Comment: @CrazyChucky The OP confused me by calling it `detect_undefined`, I thought they really meant not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll provide two solutions, the first one doesn't work exactly, but I'll leave the information in case someone sees this post a few years later.

### Solution1

[inspect.getclosurevars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars) or `func.__code__.co_names` is exactly what it is for. And it should be preferred over the 2nd solution.

```py
b = 3


def add(a):
    return a + b


print(inspect.getclosurevars(add))
# ClosureVars(nonlocals={}, globals={'b': 3}, builtins={}, unbound=set())
print(add.__code__.co_names)
# ('b',)
```

Unfortunately, there is a [bug](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80878) in it, so it won't work.

```py
import numpy as np


def add(a):
    return np.sum(a)


print(inspect.getclosurevars(add))
# ClosureVars(nonlocals={}, globals={'np': <module 'numpy' from ...>}, builtins={'sum': <built-in function sum>}, unbound=set())
print(add.__code__.co_names)
# ('np', 'sum')
# Note: sum is incorrectly detected as a built-in function.
```

### Solution2

Use the [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module to analyze the function in bytecode. Below is an example of the information that dis provides.

```py
b = 3


def add(a):
    return np.sum([a, b])


print(dis.dis(add))
```

Result:

```
 10           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (np)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (sum)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (b)
              8 BUILD_LIST               2
             10 CALL_METHOD              1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, `LOAD_GLOBAL` lines are what you are looking for. Now we can parse the lines and extract the names.

To parse the above result, [dis.get_instructions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.get_instructions) is more useful.

```py
def detect_undefined(func):
    for ins in dis.get_instructions(func):
        if inspect.iscode(ins.argval):  # inner function
            yield from detect_undefined(ins.argval)
        elif ins.opname == "LOAD_GLOBAL":  # global variable
            yield ins.argval
```

Here is the complete code with some tests.

```py
import dis
import inspect
import numpy as np


def detect_undefined(func):
    for ins in dis.get_instructions(func):
        if inspect.iscode(ins.argval):  # inner function
            yield from detect_undefined(ins.argval)
        elif ins.opname == "LOAD_GLOBAL":  # global variable
            yield ins.argval


def add1(a):
    return np.sum(a)

print(list(detect_undefined(add1)))
# ['np']


def add2(a):
    import numpy as np
    return np.sum(a)

print(list(detect_undefined(add2)))
# []


b = 3

def add3(a):
    return a + b

print(list(detect_undefined(add3)))
# ['b']


def add4(a, b=3):
    return a + b

print(list(detect_undefined(add4)))
# []


x = 0
y = 1
z = 2

def complex_func(*args, **kwargs):
    p = 0
    print(f"{x}")
    def inner1(t):
        q = y
        return lambda s: x + add3(z)
    return inner1(2)

print(list(detect_undefined(complex_func)))
# ['print', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'add3', 'z']
# Note that x is used twice, so it is detected twice.
```

One last thing to mention is that it also detects global functions. This may not be the OP's desired result, but excluding functions would be quite a challenge. Keep in mind that in Python we can assign functions to variables (`b = add`) or redefine functions as variables (`add = 0`). Or even worse, what are we supposed to do with a tuple that contains both variables and functions.